# Unity 2d mesh triangle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner at Unity. I want to create a triangle shape. Since I haven't found any pre-built triangle sprite. I tried using one with a mesh.

This is the code:

```
public class meshgenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private float h = 10;
    private float my_base = 10;
    void Start()
    {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[3];
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(my_base, 0);
        vertices[2] = new Vector3(my_base / 2, h);
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = new int[] {0, 1, 2 };
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

I didn't understand much from tutorials about meshes, but I think that the final shape should be made out of multiple triangles(a square would need 4 vertices and 2 triangles).

Also, I don't know what UV helps with. Can anyone tell me why nothing is displayed when I run this code? I created an empty object, added MeshFilter, MeshRenderer, and this script to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Untiy has a clockwise triangle winding order](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-has-a-clockwise-winding-order.129923)

Your triangle looks like

```
        2 (mybase/2, h)


0 (0,0)         1 (mybase, 0)
```

so the order of your vertices equals this image:

[image]

this results in the face normal pointing away from you, it is only visible from the other side!

You rather want the order like in this image

[image]

to make the normal face towards you.

=>

you want

```
mesh.triangles = new[]{ 0, 2, 1 };
```

in your case.